# jest error when included react-pdf renderer

Tags: react-pdf

getting moduleNameMapper error when doing yarn test, tried all the stuff by putting the same in package.json but no success.

Below is the error:

at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:501:17)
at Object. (node_modules/restructure/index.js:5:26)
at Object. (node_modules/restructure/index.js:43:4)

● Test suite failed to run

```
Configuration error:

Could not locate module ./src/EncodeStream mapped as:
<local source code path>\src\EncodeStream.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/src\/(.*)$/": "<local source code path>\src\$1"
  },
  "resolver": null
}
```

It started coming only when i included @react-pdf/renderer in one of the components

Comment: Where is your test? You probably want to include that. Right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.